# Regarding BibTex

Tags: bibtex, better-bibtex

I am using this BibTex code in beamer for the list of references, in the last. But the references List is showing without serial numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6, etc. I need the serial number too. What should I do?

Thanking you !

```
\section{References}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\nocite{*} % Insert publications even if they are not cited in the poster
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

Comment: use a style other than IEEEtran eg `\bibliographystyle{plain}`

Comment: It's not clear because it isn't a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), but I think it's more than just changing the style, because it appears to be a beamer document, and so the output is partly controlled by the beamer template. If the original style is numbered, `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]` would restore the numbers. But there are other options, and if this doesn't work, a MWE would be nice.

Comment: Members of the audience will not be able to remember the numbers you present in the slides. Better use an author-year style for the citation callouts.